# Export a .obj to .mesh format for Ogre

Tags: mesh, export, add-on

I have an .obj I want to export as a .mesh to use in [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/sdk), but I can't find how to do it. I downloaded an addon to add an option for OGRE Exporter, but the final file doesn't work with Ogre. It's a .mesh.xml and I need a .mesh only. Of course renaming the file extension doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Michael003, welcome to Blender SE.  Have you tried posting this on some sort of support channel for Ogre3D?  Does the engine give any feedback as to how this exported file isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the OgreXML converter tool.
Converts the xml to binary .mesh file.
Some of the exporters will convert it in the background for you if you set up the exporter correctly. You can also do this manually.
See the wiki below for information about the converter.

http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreXmlConverter

Comment: That is nice, I exported the mesh as .mesh.xml with blender, then I used OgreXMLConverter that converted it to .mesh and it's now usable with Ogre, thank you!